# String comparison in Java, which algorithm should I use?

Tags: java, mysql, algorithm, string-comparison, knuth-morris-pratt

I have the requirement to compare the product name that user will search with the available products. I have the name of products stored in a MySQL db. I am collecting all the names, and getting it to application level (java) once when my java service starts.

Now my string comparison scenario is something like this:

```
Available product names:
1) Samsung galaxy s2
2) Samsung galaxy s3
3) Samsung galaxy s4

User input1: galaxy s3 - Then in this scenario my 2nd result should come first as it has 2 matching keywords 'galaxy' and 's3', where other 2 has only 1 matching keyword 'galaxy'.

User input2: s3 - Then here only 2nd result should come, because the other 2 has no matching key word.

User input3: samsung - Then here all three results should come.
```

Can anyone please suggest that which algorithm will be appropriate for this in Java? And 1 more thing, bringing all the product names to application level (java) from MySQL is the right way to do it? or can I do it at MySQL level as well? (PS: I don't want to use like query on MySQL side as it will be very slow)

Comment: hava you explored String javadoc? I see that ( `String.contains()` )[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)] is pretty handy

Comment: @sanbhat: String.contains() won't give me the ranking of the results I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot @EnginePai. Lucene seems to be appropriate for my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give you some hints to develop search feature in your project:

- Use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/), just use the API or download the source code and use the custom score algorithm.
- Develop `term weighting` or `string similarity` algorithm in you own application, it will enhance your searching accuracy. (You have to search about the two concept, or take a look at the book [Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/), this really help you a lot.)
- Use mysql `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE field LIKE '%keyword%'` fuzzy searching (remember to create the index first), and apply the above `term weighting` or `string similarity` algorithm to rank the query result.

Answer (score 0):

Words in user input are separated by spacebars, so divide them into srtrings, and then use string.contains(), the longest string to match first, that will give You ranking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same thing
i used the trie([Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie))
and stored all the combination of strings that i had in trie
then you can search for the user input in trie

Note: storing all the combination in trie is not a good approach. but storing all the combinations in trie will help in search the way you want otherwise it will be prefix search.

Answer (score 0):

its not a proper way, put query for your searching

for eg:

```
SELECT productname FROM product WHERE productname='%samsung%';
```

always get the records only which are needed instead of all records.